# Rationality of moduli spaces of rational curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, birational-geometry, coarse-moduli-spaces

Let $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ be the moduli space of Deligne-Mumford stable pointed rational curves, and let us consider the quotient $\widetilde{M}_{0,n} = \overline{M}_{0,n}/S_n$.

Clearly, there is a dominant rational map $\overline{M}_{0,n}\dashrightarrow \widetilde{M}_{0,n}$, and $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ is unirational. If $n=4,5$ then $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ is a curve and a surface respectively. Thus, it is rational.

Is it known that $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ is rational for any $n\geq 3$? If so, do you know a reference for this?

Comment: $M_{0,n} / S_{n-3}$ is rational, because $M_{0,n}$ is an open subset of $(\mathbb P^1-\{0,1,\infty\} )^{n-3}$, and the quotient of that by $S_{n-3}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb A^{n-3}$ by taking coefficients of the polynomial. For the same reason, the space you want can also be expressed as a quotient of $\mathbb P^n$ by $SL_2$. This also just gives unirationality, but it might be a more fruitful vantage point for proving rationality .

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but doesn't the following work? For $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}\in k$, consider the subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ given by $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 = 0$. For generic $a_i$, this is a collection of $n$ distinct points, so we get a rational map from $\mathbb{A}^n$ to $\tilde M_{0, n}$ which is actually birational (as it's dominant and injective).

Comment: @Piotr: where did the SL2 action go?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam good point! :D

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is exactly the answer you are looking for but for even $n$ this is clearly related to the result by Katsylo for moduli spaces classical binary forms or hyperelliptic curves, see [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5726/25/1/A03;jsessionid=7DEA5C13CAD0B924289C27F8531D4C93.c3).
Another link for accessing the article by Katsylo is [this one](http://www.turpion.org/php/full/infoFT.phtml?journal_id=im&paper_id=1264).
Theorem 0.2  therein seems to give a positive answer to your rationality question for all $n$ (even or not) except possibly for $n=10$ (or genus four hyperelliptic curves). I think this exception has been covered later by Bogomolov. Note that for $n=10$ now one has an explicit description for the ring (rather than just field) of invariants, see [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717110000325) by Brouwer and Popoviciu.